# Can I have multiple answers for a question in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a trivia game for my website, but I want to have multiple answers for questions, just to make it a bit easier for people to answer. Everything I tried was wrong, so what can I do?
Javascript:

```
function quiz() {
var score=0;  
var totalQuestions=3;
alert("Welcome to my trivia game!");
alert("Make sure you answer all the questions.");

var q1=prompt("What war occured in 1812?");        
if(q1=="the 60 year war"    ) {
    score=score+1;  
    alert("Correct!"); 

} else {
    alert("Incorrect! The correct answer is the 60 year war!");  

}

var q2= prompt("When did the revolutionary war start?") ;       
if(q2=="1775"    ) {
     score=score+1; 
    alert("Correct!");  

} else {
    alert("Incorrect! The right answer is 1775!");  

}

var q3=prompt("If you're trying to fail and you succeed, did you fail or succeed?");  
if(q3=="you succeeded"  ) {
     score=score+1; 
    alert("Correct!");  

} else {
     alert("Incorrect! You succeeded!"); 

}

alert("You got " + score + " questions out of " + totalQuestions + " correct." );
```

}

Comment: Hey Owen! I have a few questions about your request. What do you exactly mean by 'multiple answers'? Could you elaborate more? From what I got you want people to be able to answer in more than one way and still score.

Comment: @ArslanAli hey thanks for trying to answer! I got an answer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OR "||" condition

```
if(q1=="the 60 year war" || "SECOND ANSWER HERE ") {
    score=score+1;  
    alert("Correct!"); 

} else {
    alert("Incorrect! The correct answer is the 60 year war!");  

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I’ll check it out.

Comment: @OwenPompa, this should do the trick. To add more possible answers just add more || conditions.